# 2 column responsive layout with sidebar overflow issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

I am using a  column responsive layout as explained in this [example script](https://codepen.io/johnstonian/pen/guhid)

CSS

```
            *, *:before, *:after {
              -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body { margin: 0; }

            .columnsContainer, footer, header { position: relative; margin: .5em; }

            .leftColumn, .rightColumn, footer, header {  border: 1px solid  #ccc; padding: 1.25em; }

            .leftColumn { margin-bottom: .5em; }

            .nav {
              list-style: none;
              margin-left: 0;
              margin-bottom: 0;
              padding-left: 0;
            }

            .nav > li,
            .nav > li > a {
              display: inline-block;
              *display: inline;
              zoom: 1;
            }

            .inline-items {
              margin-top: 0;
            }

            .inline-items li {
              margin-left: 0;
              border-left: 1px solid black;
              padding-left: 10px;
              padding-right: 10px;
            }

            .inline-items li:first-child {
              margin-left: 0;
              border: none;
              padding-left: 0;
              padding-right: 10px;
            }

            .inline-items li:last-child {
              padding-right: 0;
            }

            /* MEDIA QUERIES */
            @media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
              .leftColumn { margin-right: 19.5em; }

                .rightColumn { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 18.75em; }   
            }
```

But my site is breaking when I am having very limited content (eg:404 page) in the main column area. The footer comes up and goes under the sidebar - [see this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvxgZz).

I have done a lot of searching and trial error things before raising this question. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: The example script you are using as reference has a lot of flaws. I recommend looking up a more up to date method or a grid system framework. It is the "position: absolute" on the right column which is causing the issue because it brings the element out of the document flow. Try using floats instead. If you are dead set on this method, someone in the comments revised the code, you can see what they did [here](https://codepen.io/johnstonian/pen/Bpbtl)

Comment: I am new to the area of responsive designs -- this was the link I found while doing some search for responive layouts and hence I used it. I will try the modifications, or will change to a grid system.

@DerekGutierrez: Can you recommend a grid system for the beginners. 

My use is very limited - From the grid layouts I evaluated, I think more than 95% of the code I wont be using in my site. So I feel its waste of resource to load the complete grid system, when only 5% of it is actually needed.

Comment: The link I provided in my first comment was a solution I found to the exact script you were referencing. I totally agree, many of them are heavyweights for small projects. That said though, many of the more popular frameworks have package builders that allow you to only select the elements of the framework you need so you can reduce the bloat. One of my personal favorites is [Pure CSS](https://purecss.io/).  Once you see how they work and comfortable with responsive design you can try building your own.